# Loop trough a fixed list of values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a list of tables that needs to be renamed before each data migration.

I came up with the procedure below to check if the table exists and eventually rename it, appending its creation date:

```
DECLARE
     v_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
     v_date varchar2(50); 
     v_table varchar2(50);
     v_table_short varchar2(50);

BEGIN
    v_table:='MT_TABLE_1';
    v_table_short:=SUBSTR(v_table,8);

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM dba_tables
    WHERE owner = 'OWNER'
    AND table_name = v_table;

      IF(v_cnt > 0) THEN
        select CREATED into v_date FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OBJECT_NAME=v_table;
        execute immediate 'rename "'||v_table||'" to "'||v_table_short||'_'||v_date||'"';
      END IF;

    v_table:='MY_TABLE_2';
    v_table_short:=SUBSTR(v_table,8);

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM dba_tables
    WHERE owner = 'OWNER'
    AND table_name = v_table;

      IF(v_cnt > 0) THEN
        select CREATED into v_date FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OBJECT_NAME=v_table;
        execute immediate 'rename "'||v_table||'" to "'||v_table_short||'_'||v_date||'"';
      END IF;
END;
/
```

Now I want to avoid defining the v_table variable manually and repeating the code for each of the objects that I need to check for: is there a way to insert them as a list in a table variable or so, and have the code loop for each of the values there?

Thank you.

Comment: You can put all those table names in a table and run a cursor for each table name.

Comment: Aside from _how_ to do this, I'd strongly question the "why".  You should not be constantly renaming tables .. especially to give them a name that includes actual business data (the date).  This is a seriously flawed data model.  Your table should include a column that indicates a date that would otherwise map to the date that you are attempting to append to the table name.  Throw in partitioning on that column if you are licensed for it.

Comment: @EdStevens yes I do agree that the data model I am working with is quite flawed. Basically these tables are used during data migrations as such: they are copied 1:1 from the original tables, I then do run some of the needed updates on the data as needed from business logic on here, and then all is picked by the ETL package and fed to the target DB undergoing some more transformations on the way there.

Comment: I would say that I would need to work on the migration so that none of the transformations takes place on the source DB. But I am working on a quite large legacy migration code, so this is gonna take time and good thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I like @Srinika's idea. Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE table_list (
  sort_order NUMBER             UNIQUE,
  long_name  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) PRIMARY KEY,
  short_name VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO table_list VALUES (1,'MY_TABLE_1','MYTAB1'); 
INSERT INTO table_list VALUES (2,'MY_TABLE_2','MYTAB2');
```

I've added a column for the short name instead of computing it on the fly, as two tables might have the same first 8 characters in the name. The short_name needs to be unique else two tables will end up with the same short name. The sort order is only to do the renaming in the same order every time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rename_tables AS
  v_date       VARCHAR2(8);
  v_short_name VARCHAR2(128);
  v_stmt       VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_date := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM table_list ORDER BY sort_order) LOOP
    v_short_name := r.short_name || '_' || v_date;
    v_stmt := 'rename '||r.long_name||' to '||v_short_name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END rename_tables;
/
```

Calling this procedure would produce the output:

```
rename MY_TABLE_1 to MYTAB1_20200330
rename MY_TABLE_2 to MYTAB2_20200330
```

You'll need to add checks if the long table exists, and whether a renamed table is already there. I'd log the statements to a log table, too.

Regarding `"`: I would use them only if you have mixed case table names in the database.

Comment: Agreed, I said so in my answer. This is not finished code, but just a starting point. Actually, I didn't write down the logging bit. It's in now.

Comment: No worries, just because you are dealing with DDL, its bit scary to skip exception.

Comment: Thank you all for the great input! The idea of storing the values in an actual table just flew over my head when I was thinking this over. Naturally I will need to work on @wolφi suggestion to implement the existence check as said, sort out the date (I wanna take the date when the table was created and not the current SYSDATE), and work on logging and exceptions.